# Why are some recent versions of Geoserver not available on https://docs.geoserver.org?

Tags: geoserver

Looking at https://docs.geoserver.org/ it seems odd that under the older versions the links stop at v2.13.2.  Did the community stop publishing the interactive HTML document at some point such that we now have to find a way to the page where it has to be downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are actually going to stop providing anything other than main, stable and maintenance due to lack of resources to keep documents online: the company that provided the old doc server is no more, the project has no budget, so we'll move the docs to GitHub pages, which has a space limitation allowing only 3 versions of the doc to be published.

However, each release comes with a zip file with documentation. Go to the `http://geoserver.org/download/`, move to the archived tab, pick the one you want, e.g., `http://geoserver.org/release/2.12.4/`, follow the "user guide HTML", save and unpack the zip. You now have the docs you need.

Comment: Hmm, looks like the docs/help are again all available again up till version 2.20 (ex. https://docs.geoserver.org/2.20.x/en/user/). Was that a conscious choice?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something changed in the release process some time ago (2.13.x was quite a while ago). To be honest I didn't know we had ever provided hosted copies of any version of the manual except for `Development`, `Stable` and `Maintenance`. In principal you should never need a manual that is older than `Maintenance` as that means you are running an unsupported version.

If you desperately need a specific version (to complete a collection maybe) then you can find a zipped copy of the HTML manual under the `Archived` tab of the [Download page](http://geoserver.org/download/).

I'll probably raise a ticket about that documentation page as it has broken links too, so expect all the old links to go soon.

Comment: Well thanks.  I already found a copy I need and downloaded it.  It just would have been nice if the online, interactive docs were still there for 2.15, 2.16, and so forth.  It's a minor inconvenience to have to download it manually.  By the way, upgrading Geoserver isn't particularly easy.  A lot of teams will always need older versions of Geoserver due to environments where upgrades are not possible so I disagree with the assertion that we shouldn't need old versions of documents.  I often have to support environments where an older version was installed and hasn't been upgraded yet.

Comment: Upgrading GeoServer is trivially easy - we go to great lengths to maintain backward comparability, all you have to do is download the new war file and an extensions you use and unpack them to the servlet container.

Comment: No it isn't.  We almost always have trouble and have to spend days investigating problems.  It typically takes 1 to 2 months to upgrade, regression test, and solve problems.

Comment: I would suggest you are doing something wrong then - may be you should contract some professional help http://geoserver.org/support/

Comment: Yes we have and it's been outsourced to an entire team of contractors.  I don't trust what you are saying at all.  A large scale system has to go through at least a month of regression testing so the idea that a team could simply upgrade Geoserver and ship the product is obviously preposterous.  Release notes have to be carefully reviewed, regression testing has to be planned and performed, and issues discovered have to be investigated.

Comment: Well if I was that paranoid I would certainly not be running an out of support version with known security risks - you do know we (the GeoServer team) run extensive tests before releasing a new version. We'd love to hear if you find a regression.

Comment: As Ian I'm a GeoServer PSC member, can confirm we work very hard to preserve backward compatibilty. Regressions might happen on areas that are not covered by our continuous tests, and they are normally fixed. If you can't participate to the community directly, choose a contractor that is among the ones listed in the support page linked by Ian. There are many claiming good knowledge, but then they don't share what they do back with the community like we do, just causing more trouble.

Comment: I will take all of these comments into consideration.  Maybe it is time I start double checking the work of our contractor team to make sure I understand why it takes so long to upgrade.  It usually takes them 2 months.  Perhaps you are both right and we are making it too difficult on ourselves for some reason.